# Save content of textarea to file and load from PHP server page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

how to save content of textarea of html page into a file and  load it in PHP server page using ajax (no JQuery)??
Html page will be like this :

```
<html>
<body>
     <textarea id="editor"></textarea> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share what you have tried

Comment: use a form post then to save it in a FILE in php.

Comment: i am trying to make text editor i have added the styled text that i have done in iframe to content of text area using this :var frameObj = document.getElementById("frame");
    
     var frameContent = frameObj.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
     that.txtarea.innerHTML=frameContent; now i am willing to save the content of text area that i got from iframe to a file and load it to PHP server page using ajax

Comment: @RohitBatra how can you give me an example??

Comment: @UtsabNeupane Can you show a running example of what you did on jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ux95g0o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.This will give you the structure for your application and please note this code has not been tested.

**Server.php**

```
<html>
<script>
var baseUrl="service.php";
function submitFormAjax()
{
    var xmlhttp= window.XMLHttpRequest ?
        new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // Here is the response
    }

    var data = document.getElementById('editor').value;

    xmlhttp.open("POST",baseUrl,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("action=write&data=" + data);
}
function readDataAjax()
{
    var xmlhttp= window.XMLHttpRequest ?
        new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            document.getElementById('editor').value=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST",baseUrl,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("action=read");
}
</script>
<body onload="readDataAjax()">
<form method="post">
     <textarea id="editor" name="editor"></textarea> 
     <button onClick="submitFormAjax();return false;">Submit</button>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
$fileName="newfile.txt";
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    switch($_POST['action'])
    {
    case 'read';
        echo file_get_contents($fileName);
    break;

    case 'write';
        if( isset($_POST['data']))
        {
            $myfile = fopen($fileName, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $txt = $_POST['data'];
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            fclose($myfile);
            echo "file successfully saved";
        }
    break;
    }

}

?>

?>
```

Comment: its not working it is making file but content are not being  stored  so what to do on it??

Comment: Check now.I dont have php installed hence i can't test the code.But should work fine now.It was due to the way i had accessed the value of the editor element."document.getElementById('editor').innerHtml" was changed to "document.getElementById('editor').value".